# What is meant by fractional oxidation state?

Tags: redox

What is the real concept behind oxidation state?

Comment: Title and body don't cooperate here well... You should elaborate.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/69798/an-introduction-to-oxidation-state-oxidation-number

Answer (score 5):

Nothing too much, really. When you have a compound like sodium tetrathionate $\ce{Na_2S_4O_6}$, if you calculate the oxidation state of sulfur, you get $\frac{5}{2}$. This means that the AVERAGE oxigation state of sulfur is $\frac{5}{2}$. In fact, the sulfurs in the compound are not equal, you have two of them with an oxidation state of $+5$, and two of them with $0$. But when you balance redox equations, you do not really care about this, and you can use the average value of $2.5$ to find the coefficients.